# Complicated job aggregate

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a very complicated job process and it's not 100% clear to me where to handle what.
I don't want to have code, it just the question who is responsible for what.

Given is the following:

1. There is a root directory "C:\server"
2. Inside are two directories "ftp" and "backup"

Imagine the following process:

1. An external customer sends a file into the ftp directory.
2. An importer application get's the file and now the fun starts.
3. A job aggregate have to be created for this file.
4. The command "CreateJob(string file)" is fired.
   ?. The file have to be moved from ftp to backup. Inside the CommandHandler or inside the Aggregate or on JobCreated event?
5. StartJob(Guid jobId) get's called. A third folder have to be created "in-progress", File have to be copied from backup to in-progress. Who does it?

So it's unclear for me where Filesystem things have to be handled if the Aggregate can not work correctly without the correct filesystem.
Because my first approach was to do that inside an Infrastructure layer/lib which listen to the events from the job layer. But it seems not 100% correct?!

And top of this, what is with replaying?
You can't replay things/files that were moved, you have to somehow simulate that a customer sends the file to the ftp folder...

Thankful for answers

Comment: why are files moved in the `backup` folder and then moved again in the `in-progress` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file have to be moved from ftp to backup. Inside the CommandHandler or inside the Aggregate or on JobCreated event?

In situations like this, I move the file to the destination folder in the `Application` service that sends the command to the `Aggregate` (or that calls a command-like method on the `Aggregate`, it's the same) **before the command is sent** to the `Aggregate`. In this way, if there are some problems with the file-system (not enough permissions or space is not available etc) the command is not sent. These kind of problems should not reach our `Aggregate`. We most protect it from the infrastructure. In fact we should keep the `Aggregate` isolated from anything else; it must contain **only pure business logic** that is used to decide what events get generated.

> Because my first approach was to do that inside an Infrastructure layer/lib which listen to the events from the job layer. But it seems not 100% correct?!

Indeed, this seems like over engineering to me. You must KISS.

> StartJob(Guid jobId) get's called. A third folder have to be created "in-progress", File have to be copied from backup to in-progress. Who does it?

Whoever's calling the `StartJob` could do the moving, before the `StartJob` gets called. Again, keep the `Aggregate` pure. In this case it depends on your framework/domain details.

> And top of this, what is with replaying? You can't replay things/files that where moved, you have to somehow simulate that a customer sends the file to the ftp folder...

The events are loaded from the event store and replayed in two situations:

1. Before every command gets sent to the `Aggregate`, the `Aggregate Repository` loads all the events from the event store then it *applies* every one of them to the `Aggregate`, probably calling some `applyThisEvent(TheEvent)` method on the Aggregate. So, this methods should be with no side effects (pure) otherwise you change the outside world *again and again*  at every command execution and you don't want that.
2. The `read-models` (the `projections`, the `query-models`) that present data to the user listen to those events and update the database tables that hold the data that the users see. The events are sent to those read-models after they are generated and every time the read-models are being recreated. When you *invent* a new `read-model`, you must pass it all the events that were previous generated by the `aggregates` in order to build the correct/complete state on them. If your read-model's event listeners have side effects what do you think happens when you *replay* those long past events? The outside world is modified again and again and you don't want that! The read-models only interpret the events, they don't generate other events and they don't change the outside world.

There is a special third case when events reach another type of model, a `Saga`. A `Saga` **must** receive an event only once! This is the case that you thought to use in `Because my first approach was to do that inside an Infrastructure layer/lib which listen to the events from the job layer`. You *could* do this in your case but is not KISS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With replaying I mean the second case. So replaying is always just for the read model, I was not sure about that. I thought maybe it should be possible to recreate a complete system state with replaying (Folders and so on).

Comment: You could do that, if you have such a read-model but think about the files contents. You would have to keep that contents inside the events in order to have the complete data to populate the files in folders. There are all kind of read-models, it doesn't need to be a database. But keep in mind that read-models are not queried by the `Aggregates`. Read-models are not used in validating the `Aggregate's` invariants.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe you can answer me one little question more. I have for each domain layer (CustomerService, JobManagement, UserManagement) one CommandStack lib and one QueryStack lib. Problem is, the events fired by the CommandStack are inside the CommandStack. That means, the QueryStack (Denormalizers and queries) have to reference the CommandStack, just because of that. Do you suggest a third lib just for the events to avoid that?

Comment: @SharpNoiZy No, keep them inside CommandStack. The command side owns those events.

Comment: You seem to be very experienced in event sourcing. A tiny question, how do you organize large Aggregates code wise? My job aggregate has 20 properties and 10 events to apply, that means there are 10 commands and 10 commandHandlers also, that is a huge amount of code. I do a partial class for the aggregate with the event creation (Business rules) and a partial with the state (properties and Event apply) but it's still a lot of code.

Comment: By aproaching things this way you loose cohesion. Instead, try to split the Aggregate into smaller Aggregates by observing what properties/commands/events are grouped by the aggregate invariants. I had cases where an Aggregate contained two sub-aggregates with no shared invariants between them so I had split it. Refactoring is a must in DDD.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a very complicated job process and it's not 100% clear to me where to handle what. I don't want to have code, it just the question who is responsible for what.

The usual answer is that the domain model -- aka the "aggregate" makes decisions, and saves them.  Observing those decisions, some event handler induces side effects.

> And top of this, what is with replaying? You can't replay things/files that where moved, you have to somehow simulate that a customer sends the file to the ftp folder...

You replay the events to the aggregate, so that it is restored to the state where it made the last decision.  That's a separate concern from replaying the *side effects* -- which is part of the motivation for handling the side effects elsewhere.

Where possible, of course, you prefer to have the side effects be idempotent, so that a duplicated message doesn't create a problem.  But notice that from the point of view of the model, it doesn't actually matter whether the side effect succeeds or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer